# Specialized tactics books to improve position analysis?

Tags: analysis, tactics, books

I know that [Mig Greengard](https://twitter.com/chessninja) used to have the [VisualEyes column](http://www.chessninja.com/whitebelt/samples/036whitebelt.htm) in [Chess Ninja](http://www.chessninja.com/). In that column you were given a position and then a list of moves (say 3 or 4 moves forward) and then you were asked to solve the tactics problem from the position resulting from those moves.

Are there any books or other resources with positions that offer a similar experience?

---

An example might be like this:

[image]

After:

```
7. Qb3 Qe7 
8. Nc3 c6 
9. Bg5 b5
10...
```

White to move and win.

Comment: I don't know other sources that explicitly set the problems up that way, but it's also the case that solving any old tactics problem that involves variations a few moves deep requires you to mentally project the position forward in just that way anyway.

Comment: That is true, but this goes a bit deeper in that you are forced to look for the initial idea in the projected position; which I find more difficult. Once a combination has been initiated its principle variations tend to be logical and forcing. In the case I am interested in you are finding the tactical idea in a position 3 or 4 moves forward from what is on the board/diagram in front of you.

Comment: I get you, but part of my point was that in a typical problem as well, "you are finding the tactical idea in a position 3 or 4 moves forward from what is ... in front of you," as a given problem is rarely limited to a single idea, and will instead involve several different tactical ideas at different junctures. In case it's not clear, please know that the real gist of what I'm saying is very positive: I hope you can find more of these that you're looking for, but if you can't, it's good to remember that "normal" tactics problems are giving this sort of practice already.

Comment: I understand. And I think I can get a part of this from more advanced books like Tactical Chess Training (Shamkovich and Catier) by reading through some of the moves and then continuing the idea mentally.

Answer (score 1):

Larry Evans authored "What's the Best Move" in Chess Life for years.  It is what you describe - a position with multiple guess answers.  You're supposed to choose the right one, and say why.

He published a [book with the same name](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006C4UX0).

Comment: The question isn't actually asking about multiple choice problems. The "list of moves (say 3 or 4)" in Robert's question refers to a _sequence_ of moves from the initial diagram position, rather than a list of potential answers.